# Cppcheck into Jenkins with QT project

Tags: c++, jenkins, continuous-integration, cppcheck

I have server with Jenkins and QT project. The server runs on CentOS 7. I installed "**Cppcheck**" into server also I installed  "**Cppcheck Plug-in**" plugin into Jenkins.

The script for build project:

```
cd FlashClipboard;
/usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake FlashClipboard.pro;
make clean;
make;
cppcheck --enable=all --suppress=missingIncludeSystem . --xml --xml-version=2 . 2> ./tmp/cppcheck.xml;
```

Post-Build Actions:

[image]

But I have error:

> [Cppcheck] Starting the cppcheck analysis.
>
> [Cppcheck] Processing 1 files with the pattern 'tmp/cppcheck.xml'.
>
> [Cppcheck] Parsing throws exceptions. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>
> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flash%20Clipboard/tmp/cppcheck.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
>
> Build step 'Publish Cppcheck results' changed build result to FAILURE
>
> Build step 'Publish Cppcheck results' marked build as failure

What is my mistake?

Comment: Does `tmp` folder exist?

Comment: @VTT Yes, tmp folder exists

Comment: the file is blank i think and you do not ignore blank files in your CPPCheck plugin configuration.

Comment: if you check other questions for "Premature end of file" it seem my comments is correct, I don't have time to try it out right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry but are you sure the path is correct?

Shouldn't it be:

```
Cppcheck report XML:  FlashClipboard/tmp/cppcheck.xml
```